# How can I add an incrementing ID to a table in my database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble inserting created account info into my database. Here is my code:

```
 $fname=$_POST['fname'];
 $lname=$_POST['lname'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 $state=$_POST['state'];
 $zip=$_POST['zip'];
 $address1=$_POST['address1'];
 $address2-$_POST['address2'];
 $number=$_POST['number'];

 $query="insert into Customers('$email','$password','$fname','$lname','$address1',
    '$address2',$zip,'$state',$number)";
```

I need one more column though. At the beginning I need the customerID which the user does not input. I am having trouble figuring out how to get the code to read in what the largest CustomerID is in the database then adding one onto it every time a new account is made. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there more code? Where is the part that actually executes the query? Are there any error messages that you're getting? Have you considered setting CustomerID as primary key with auto-increment ? If you set CustomerID as auto-increment then you will not need to specify it in your query.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And you do your insert first, then use last_insert_id() to retrieve the ID the database assigned.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table in the database you create a column at the start "customerID". In the properties for this, you check "auto-increment". When we then add a new row to the table...the row increments by 1

Comment: Yeah I just got that to work now. Except it seems as if the database is not reading in what i have inside $query=".....";

Comment: Could you post your connection method and your query